# How to print on physically printer a JPG file in C++

Tags: image, c++11, printing, visual-studio-2013, jpeg

I need some help. I wrote print function on Linux with cups API. Now I must print jpg or other image file on Windows with C++ code. I have to do this silently without any dialogs/GUI. I can't find any examples that would help me. Could somebody help? Important is that I must use compiler mvsc2013 and I can't use QT ("becuse it is to heavy").

Or maybe someone have any idea how to print PDF file? Now I convert pdf to image. But I don't know how to print it.

Comment: Ok. I need to print on default printer. But can I from shell get job status? I have to check if the printing is completed or is an error. Is this possible from shell?

Comment: I found something like this ShellExecute(NULL, "print", szDocumentPath, NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);  but I dont know how to get status.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to handle this as usual bitmap printing. Load JPG with GDI+, open printer DC, blit an image to DC. End of story.

Comment: Thx for answer. Could You give me some example? I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you have some code example? Please help me.